# Timestamp to yyyymmdd hhmm but only keep hhmm

Tags: php, date, format, timestamp, string-formatting

I have a timestamp in the database. With the following code I can format it to the right date:

```
    $datefrom=mysql_real_escape_string($record['projectdatefrom']);
    $date1 = date("Y/m/d", $datefrom);
```

Then I give the input vield the `value="$date1`.

Now I have another field for the `H:i`, so I'd like to have them seperate from each other.

Can can I cut the `Y/m/d` of the `$date1` and only return the `H:i`?

Was trying doing things like this:      `$datetest = date("H:i", $datefrom);` but no success.

Comment: $datetest = date("H:i", $datefrom); should work, is your $datefrom variable a unix time ?

Answer (score 0):

`$datefrom` will need to be a UNIX timestamp. `strtotime()` can be useful for generating one off a plain-text or MySQL-style date string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape the string after it was returned from the DB.

Therefore:

```
$date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($record['projectdatefrom']));
$time = date("H:i", strtotime($record['projectdatefrom']));
```

Or using `DateTime`:

```
$dt = new DateTime($record['projectdatefrom']);
$date = $dt->format('Y/m/d');
$time = $dt->format('H:i');
```